# ¿Cómo Separar nombre y apellidos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando separar los nombres y apellidos en mysql que se encuentra en una sola columna, pero sin éxito. Habrá alguna manera de obtener este resultado.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nombres, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS PrimerNombre, 
IF( LENGTH(nombres) - LENGTH(REPLACE(nombres, ' ', ''))>1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nombres, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) ,NULL) AS SegundoNombre, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nombres, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS Apellidos FROM alumno
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega lo que has intentado

Comment: Gracias por tu apreciación

Comment: No hay una forma canónica de separar nombres y apellidos. Incluso con un diccionario de nombres o de apellidos, el riesgo de cometer errores es alto. Hay personas que tienen más de 2 nombres, solo 1 apellido o apellidos compuestos, como _del Castillo_ o _de la Roca_. Mi recomendación es que si necesitas nombres y apellidos separados, lo mejor es que los captures así, por separado, pues el criterio humano no es fácil de sustituir en este caso.